# Convert Time of day in string format to c# timespan

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a value like `3:30pm` as a javascript string.

I have an MVC controller which takes a parameter which is a `TimeSpan`.

I make a jquery post to the controller. How do I get the time from string format into the `TimeSpan` format?

Comment: `TimeSpan` stores an interval of time, not a concrete time. The only way to use time span to represent time is to store interval from some specific time, f.e the midnight. Is that what you want?

Comment: @pwas Yes, I want store the time from midnight.

Comment: Ok, so you need to write own model binder because `TimeSpan` has no default paremeterless ctor, so it cannot be binded by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `TimeSpan` has no default ctro (parameterless) so default model binder cannot be used. You need to write your own:

```
public class TimeModelBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var hour = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["hours"];
        var minutes = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["minutes"];
        var time = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(Hour), int.Parse(minutes), 0);
        return return time;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(TimeModelBinder))] TimeSpan model)
{
}
```

Post:

```
$.post("/home/index",  {
         hours: 5,
         minutes: 10  }, function() {
              //success
         });
```

*Written from memory*

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to parse your javascript string to DateTime you can do:

```
DateTime.TimeOfDay
```

afterwards which will represent the part of the day elapsed since midnight as a TimeSpan.